# In Rust using warp, how do I build filters by configuration?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-warp

Starting with a root path:

```rust
let root = warp::path::end()
  .map(|| "Hello World, at root!");
```

I would like to construct `.or()` Filters by configuration:

```rust
for path in web_server_config.paths {
  root.or(warp::path(path).map(|| "OK"));  // or any configurable response
}
```

I understand now that `root` is cloned into `or()` and returns a new instance and a different type that wraps the original type. So I would make `root` mutable and reassign on each result of `or()`, but I don't how to type `root` correctly so that it can accept `or()` results, and satisfy `warp::serve`

Comment: You failed to provide the necessary `use` statements and a workable stub of `web_server_config`.

Comment: `web_server_config` here is arbitrary and in this example has a paths property being a Vector of strings.